# How to get value by value of an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I got a problem, I got a array from a sql query and I want to associate each value of this array to an index value.

```
array(16) { ["noCommande"]=> string(5) "49083" ["dateCommande"]=> string(19) "2007-02-21 18:24:04" ...
```

So here I just want to get back each value one per one. The `array[i]` doesn't work so I am a bit in trouble.

Thanks you for your support.

Comment: This is an associative array, not a numerically indexed one. You access values by their string key, not their position in the array. `echo $array['noCommande'];`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: For example -->  noCommande : 49083

Comment: @JohnConde I get back this datas from a query with fetch_assoc that's bad ? I should use fetch_array no ?

Comment: actually @HoareauThomas fetch_assoc makes it easier to write code because you can use the column names to get values in your code, so even if you get an entire result row you can still get only 1 column from your result if you want

Comment: @JohnConde I tried that you said and it works ! Sorry guys I don't use array usually

Comment: Do you know `loops`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate like below:-

```
foreach($your_array as $key=>$value){

   echo $key.'-'.$value;
    echo "<br/>";//for new line to show in a good manner
}
```

It will output like :- noCommande - 49083 and etc.

Comment: That works but the datas had to go in a file .txt so I adapted your solution but it works. The only problem who are very strange is that my query get a lot of rows and only one of them is displayed.

Comment: Your solution works, I just adapted this to my work because the datas should go in txt file.

Comment: As I said the query shows me only the first row. Do you have a idea about that ?

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes.

Comment: I think it's a problem with my treatment of my query. I don't use while loop to get back the datas.

Comment: I do that `while($resultat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  foreach($resultat as $key=>$resultat){
   fwrite($fichier,$key);
   fwrite($fichier,": ");
   fwrite($fichier,$resultat);
   fwrite($fichier,"\n");
  }
  fwrite($fichier,"\n");
 }`

Comment: thanks. you can put question for that no issue.and meanwhile vote-up also my answer if possible

Comment: Just a little thing, do u know why a part of my last row is repete again. Just a part of my last row is repete. It's very strange @anant

Answer (score 1):

It's associative array, values are in

```
$array['noCommande'];
$array['dateCommande'];
```

etc.

If you want to ake a loop over array and write all values,

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ': ' . $value; // echoes 'noCommande: 49083', etc.
}
```